# Cracking Salted Peoplesoft Hashes

Tags: hash, password-cracking, hashcat

So I felt the saga of my last post was getting too long (linked here: [Unknown round length makes hash uncrackable?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187401/unknown-round-length-makes-hash-uncrackable)) so I would create a new one addressing the current problem as it stands. My new avenue is looking like the hashed passwords and salts I have collected are Peoplesoft hashes due to an identification from this tool: https://github.com/psypanda/hashID. To test if that is a false positive I planned to use hashcat to crack my known account hash, which I have the salt and plain text password to, but they only have a mode for unsalted PeopleSoft hashes.

There is a bit of old work done here (https://github.com/kholia/ReversingPeopleSoft) to reverse how PeopleSoft performs salted hash generation but that appears dead.

Does anyone have any leads on how the hash is performed so I can try and recreate my hash to check if it is a PeopleSoft variety or know of a way to coerce Hashcat into using it with a different mode?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hashcat currently (Nov 2018) only supports unsalted PeopleSoft hashes - there's no way that I know of to get Hashcat to apply an arbitrary salt to them at speed. I also haven't been able to determine what the actual algorithm is yet, and neither John the Ripper nor MDXfind appear to have support yet for salted PeopleSoft hashes.